# How to insert data into elasticsearch from csv file using java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Is there a way by which I can parse csv files using java and then insert that data into elasticsearch so that I can render it and view it on kibana?? Are there any plugins or jars available for the same??

Comment: Is Java a requirement here? Have you looked at [Logstash](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/logstash/)? It's the ETL provided by ElasticSearch in its stack.

Comment: I initially wanted to make a generic logstash config file that would work for all csv files. Posted a qn in stackoverflow regarding the same. No answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28229613/determine-the-column-names-from-the-csv-file-in-logstash-config)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [CSV River Plugin](https://github.com/AgileWorksOrg/elasticsearch-river-csv) or [Logstash](https://kevinkirsche.com/2014/08/25/using-logstash-to-import-csv-files-into-elasticsearch/) as already mentioned.